# Find cafes within certain distance of location from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the textSearchQuery method of PlacesApi (com.google.maps.PlacesApi) to find all cafes within a 1000 m radius from a particular location. My problem is that cafes outside the given radius are being returned too. How can I find only the cafes within the radius?

Note: I want to implement this in a Java program instead of JavaScript(+HTML).

This is my textSearchQuery call:

```
PlacesSearchResponse response = PlacesApi.textSearchQuery(context, "cafe")
  .location(currentPoint)//where currentPoint = new LatLng(13.039083, 77.610890)
  .radius(1000)//1 KM
  .await()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Places Search (example)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) instead of a `textSearchQuery`.

From the docs, [Text search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) won't filter results outside of given bounds:

> You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a radius parameter. This will instruct the Places service to prefer showing results within that circle. **Results outside the defined area may still be displayed**.